# Why do I keep getting NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, nameerror

I'm a noob to coding and just began my question. I started with python OOP and I ran into some trouble.

```
class Multidiv:
    def __init__(self, mulitple):
        self.mulitple = mulitple

    def mulitple(self, x, y):
        return x * y
    
    def divide(self, x, y):
        pass


math = Multidiv(mulitple, 10, 5)
print(math)
```

I keep getting a nameError and I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: what is the variable `mulitple` in `Multidiv(mulitple, 10, 5)`

Comment: Again completely new. I wanted to use math as a variable that when called with print on line 13 would provide  the values of  10 and 5 multiplied.

Comment: `mulitple` is not defined when you're sending it to the init function..

Comment: So in  order to define it I would have to create an instance where mulitple = two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a lot of mess in your code.. I suggest you get back to reading documentation/watching videos.
for starter - `mulitple` is not defined.
secondly, you're sending 10 and 5 but ignoring them in the init function. they won't get into to mulitple function.

you can do what you're trying to achieve like this:

```
class Multidiv:
    def __init__(self, mulitple):
        self.action = mulitple #save the string name as a member of the object.

    def mulitple(self, x, y):
        return x * y

    def divide(self, x, y):
        pass

math = Multidiv('mulitple') #pass the action name with qoutes as string, otherwise it won't be recognized.
actual_action = getattr(math, math.action) # use builtin function getattr to get the actual wanted method out of the object. (you can read about getattr online)
print(actual_action(10, 5)) call the actual action with the parameters you wish to calculate
```

Comment: Can you please recommend me a OOP documentation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with specific official OOP python docs, but `geeksforgeeks` have some nice article about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-oops-concepts/
In addition, you can always google for concepts or specific issues.
and there's also the official python docs: https://docs.python.org/